# Library .h File Not Found

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps

Everytime I open my iOS project in Xcode, and then I try to compile it, I get the error: **'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found**

So then I have to drag both the GoogleMaps.bundle and GoogleMaps.framework to **Target > Bluid Phases > Link Binary With Libraries** and the it compiles with no problem.

But it's always a pain to do this procedure everytime I open my project.

*Does anyone happen to know how to solve this?*

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `use_frameworks!` defined in your `Podfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem. Maybe this will help somebody to get rid of this daily headache.

---

### Problem

In my project, the name of the folder (in Finder, not Xcode) that contains the Google Maps library is called:

***"Google Maps"***

*Do you see the **space** between the word "**Google**" and the word **"Maps"**?*

Well, that was the problem!

For some reason, *Xcode* could **not** find that library just because of that beautiful ***space***.

---

### Consequence

I selected my project and went to **Build Settings**.

I could find there the Google Maps library being referenced in:

1. Framework Search Path
2. Library Search Path
3. Header Search Path

for the 3 sections: ***Debug, Distribution and Release.***

But *Instead* of being referenced as:

- *Line   i:*  **$(PROJECT_DIR)/Google Maps**

It was referenced as:

- *Line   i:*  **$(PROJECT_DIR)/Google**
- *Line i+1:*  **Maps**

*(Line i and Line i+1 were not there, I put them just to explain myself better)*

And this didn't allow Xcode to find the Google Maps library.

---

### Solution

I just changed those 2 lines references of the Google Maps library for this:

- *Line i:*  **"$(PROJECT_DIR)/Google Maps"**

Please, note the ***double quotes*** at the begging and at the end of the path.

***Those double quotes solved the problem.***

I made this change in those 3 parts (Framework Search Path, Library Search Path
and Header Search Path).

---

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `$(SRCROOT)/Pods/*YourGoogleMapsFolder*` to your `Framework Search Paths` in Build Settings. This might be a temporary fix as well, but at least you shouldn't have to change anything every time you open your project.